# Css/C# Make element "disappear" on print

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, printing

I have a pretty simple View which Renders a Child View for each Object handed over by the Controler. Information for each Object is than printet on a seperate page. All of this works fine. However i would like to have a headline on top of the page which is not printed. Using the Css I use this works, however the first printed page will be a blank one. If I just outcomment the headline the blank page disappears again. Is there any way of having the Headline there without printing a blank page?

View:

```
@model IQueryable<Event>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Druckansicht";
}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.print();
        })
    </script>
}

<h1 class="no-print">Deine Druckansicht vom @ViewBag.StartDate bis zum @ViewBag.EndDate</h1>

@foreach (Event evnt in Model)
{
    <div class="page-break">
        @{Html.RenderAction("PrintChild", "Events", new { ID = evnt.EventID });}
    </div>
}
```

Css:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print
    {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .page-break
    {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
}
```

Linking to the Stylesheet etc. is done in a _Layout View.

This is the Solution I ended up using:

CSS:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print
    {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .page-break
    {
        page-break-after: always;
    }

    .page-break-last
    {
         page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
        int i = Model.Count();
        foreach (Musa.Models.Event evnt in Model)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                <div class="page-break page-break-last">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("PrintChild", "Events", new { ID = evnt.EventID });}
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="page-break">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("PrintChild", "Events", new { ID = evnt.EventID });}
                </div>
            }
            i--;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What about height=0, overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would work:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print
    {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .page-break
    {
        page-break-after: always;
    }

    .last-page{
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

With the following html:

```
<h1 class="no-print">Header</h1>

<div class="page-break">Test 1</div>
<div class="page-break">Test 2</div>
<div class="page-break last-page">Test 3</div>
```

So make sure the last item get's an additonal class tag otherwise you will get a blank page at the end.